# XSLT generate random ID ( letters or numbers or both)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, guid, auto-generate

This is my code which is working, it seems it uses version 1.0 but I am not sure if some other version can be used also?
Now I need to add just one more element which will have some unique ID sent below the STATUS element, for example CORRELATIONID.
How to add it in most simple way? I read something similar for version 2.0 but I am not sure if this is applicable to my code so please tell me what should I do?
I am using solely XSLT not with C# or anything similar.
Thank you

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <max:SyncMXWO Destination="SCCD" Action="urn:processDocument"> 
      <max:MXWOSet>
      <max:WORKORDER>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateTaskAssignmentEx/Task" />
      </max:WORKORDER>
      </max:MXWOSet> 
    </max:SyncMXWO> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="Task"> 
    <max:WONUM><xsl:value-of select="CallID"/></max:WONUM> 
    <max:STATUS>COMPLETE</max:STATUS>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? If you don't know, find out - see here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: hi michael it is not maybe version 1.0 like it is written at the head on the XSLT message?

Comment: No, that doesn't mean anything about what your processor **can** do. -- Besides, there's no random function in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. You will need to use an extension function - if your processor supports extensions.

Comment: Hi Michael result is Microsoft and 1. Please help me what should I do since I am not so experienced with XSLT

Comment: You will need to use one of the languages that Microsoft supports as an extension - see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: michael I am really not so skilled I do not know what shol I do can you please give me example how guid should be implemented? if you can please?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know any more about it than what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think using

```
  <xsl:template match="Task"> 
    <max:WONUM><xsl:value-of select="CallID"/></max:WONUM> 
    <max:STATUS>COMPLETE</max:STATUS>
    <CORRELATIONID><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></CORRELATIONID>
  </xsl:template>
```

should suffice to generate a unique id for each `Task` element you process in a single run of your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: I don't know about that. This question is tagged `guid`. The IDs generated here will be unique only within the scope of a single transformation - certainly not globally.

Comment: I did not see that tag, I only went by the text asking for a random id, letters or numbers or both. Let's see what the original poster says, generating guids is certainly not done by `generate-id()`.

Comment: Hi Martin and Michael thank you for your involvment. this message is sent toward the external system through the ESB  integration. ESB system expects message where unique ID will be generated for that message which will be sent and we use XSLT to define the message. We need for example in that CORRELATIONID to send unique ID (regardles if it contains only letters or only numbers or both but the main point is that ESB system should not receive message with same CORRELATIONID value so we need some ID value which will not be repeated in short time interval I know in other languages it is possible

Comment: Which XSLT processor from Microsoft is that, is it .NET based (`XslCompiledTransform` or `XslTransform`) or COM based (a version of MSXML)? And you say `I am using solely XSLT not with C# or anything similar`, does that mean you don't call the XSLT processor with .NET code?